# Parallel hint v/s DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE

Tags: oracle11g, parallel-processing, hint

What is the difference between parallel hint and DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE on an INSERT or MERGE statement  in ORACLE?

Answer (score 1):

`parallel` hint

- does a statement-level parallelism,
- is coordinated inside the SQL engine,
- is a single statement within a single transaction - implies no commits

`dbms_parallel_execute` package

- does an application-level parallelism,
- is coordinated in a PL/SQL program,
- is multiple statements within multiple transactions - implies commits of partially DML'd data.

You better read the Oracle documentation.